# position image at bottom of div without wrapper

Tags: javascript, image, html, position

How would I position an image at the bottom of a div using JavaScript without wrapping it? I understand I can wrap it with a div and do absolute positioning, but that muddies up the markup and it's dynamic content too, so I can't wrap the image, it has to target an image in a specific div.

Here is the basic markup, need it to find height of div, then position image at bottom. i think that is how it would work?

```
<div id="content">
 <p>some text</p>
 <img src="img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: wrappers and absolute positioning are the only ways to do it reliably cross-browser.  It doesn't really muddies up the markup.

Comment: I've had problems doing absolute position on images, unless I wrap them. that is definitely muddied markup. unless I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can position an image as well to the bottom of a DIV, you don’t need to add a second wrapper.
Either do it in CSS:

```
div { position: relative; } 

div > img { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

or do the same thing in JS if you need it be in JS.

Comment: this is css3 though isn't it? it wont translate to older ie. I need it to be consistant. I've never really used > in css though, very unfamiliar to this concept. can you elaborate what it is?

Comment: @Lukasz, what versions of IE do you need to support?  Also, for a description of CSS selectors, I suggest googling "css selectors" or viewing http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/css-cheat-sheet/

Comment: It’s just a sample and depending on the actually code, you can remove the > and it’ll work in all IE versions. Just that it might also affect some other images somewhere else on your application/site.

Comment: @Lukasz As far as I know... the only IE version not supporting the '>' (Direct descendant) selector is version 6. Which is ten years old.

Answer (score 2):

## As simple as this~~

```
#content
{ position:relative; padding-bottom:50px; } // if image height is 50px;
#content > img
{ position:absolute; bottom:0; }
```

That should do it.
If you don’t use **padding-bottom** in the second rule, the image will be overflowed (and will cover the text) if the content of the div (its text) is not taller that the image height.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using CSS for sure, and don't recommend doing it this way.. but you can do it with JS like so

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KCFvv/)**

```
var image = document.getElementById("image"),
    contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");

image.style.position = 'absolute';
image.style.top = contentDiv.offsetTop + contentDiv.offsetHeight - image.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: Using Javascript for something that you can achieve with two rules in CSS is a little too much I think.

Comment: heh.. I agree.. but thats what the OP asked for. Not sure a down vote is really called for honestly.

Comment: you are right, I did not noticed that he first asked for JS. Removing evil down vote~

Comment: how cross browser is the css bit?